# Node.js - Cron.js stops working after running over 12 hours.

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am writting a node.js application that creates crons that pulls data from several sources, these are dynamic so the jobs that pull data are changing all the time and they are managed through an API, I am using cron.js. However for some reason these keep on getting stuck after running over 12 hours.

Any ideas on why this could be happening, I am try-catching the code on all the jobs and the application, and no error is shown. :(

Any ideas? should I change the cron.js approach?

Comment: can you restart the app after 6 hours? usally, node apps boot in a second, so if missing 1 seconds every 6 hours is tolerable, you won't crash unexpectedly anymore.

Comment: Yes I can, I just want to know if there are any options available. :)

Comment: due to the long "trial runs", that kind of detective work is challenging. Could be ram/garbage, http pool saturation, http timeouts, etc. If you use any NPM modules, there's a whole 'nother huge vector. You can use lots of logs to try to figure your problem, but if it were a major known issue it would have been fixed already, so it's likely on your end. Using a scheduled app restart, i've gotten "5-9s" 24X7 on outside code that only worked for about 6 or 7 hours per stretch. sad, but true and satisfactory.

Comment: Same problem in the 3.0.3 version (2023). Sad to see that the issue was closed https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/issues/232